# Writing a program that calculates the determinant of an nxn matrix recursively

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, determinants

So i wrote a python program that calculates the determinant of an nxn matrix.
It worked perfectly for 3x3 matrices but when i tried to input a 4x4 matrix it gave me insane values not even close to the correct value so i was wondering if you could maybe show me where am i wrong in my code

```
import numpy as np
n = int(input('size:'))
mat = np.zeros((n,n))
d = 0

ep = 0
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        ep = int(input('mat[{},{}]='.format(i,j)))
        mat[i,j] = ep

def submat(l,i,p):
    m = []
    sub = np.zeros((np.shape(l)[0]-1,np.shape(l)[0]-1))
    for j in range(np.shape(l)[0]):
        for k in range(np.shape(l)[0]):
            if k == p or j == i:
                continue
            else:
                m.append(l[j][k])
    for j in range(np.shape(sub)[0]):
        for k in range(np.shape(sub)[0]):
            sub[j][k] = m[0]
            m.remove(m[0])
    return sub

def det(l,d):
    if np.shape(l) == (2,2):
        return l[0,0]*l[1,1] - l[1,0]*l[0,1]
    elif np.shape(l) == (1,1):
        return l[0,0]
    else:
        for i in range(np.shape(l)[0]):
            print(d)
            d += l[i][0]*((-1)**(i))*det(submat(l,i,0),d)
        return d
```

p.s : i checked the submat function that i wrote and the problem is definitely not there

Answer (score 0):

The problem is what ever you do with `d` in your `det` function. After removing it (I also took the liberty to remove the 2x2 special case since the Laplace expansion works for that too) I have

```
def det(l):
    d = 0
    if np.shape(l) == (1,1):
        return l[0,0]
    else:
        for i in range(np.shape(l)[0]):
            d += l[i][0]*((-1)**(i))*det(submat(l,i,0))
        return d
```

Now I compare your results to the one of the det function from `numpy.linalg`

```
maximum = 0 
argmax = None
for _ in range(10**4):
    n = 4
    mat = np.random.randint(100,10000,n**2).reshape(n,n)
    relative_error = np.abs((det(mat)-np.linalg.det(mat))/np.linalg.det(mat))
    if relative_error > maximum:
        maximum = relative_error
        argmax = mat

maximum,np.linalg.det(argmax)-det(argmax),np.linalg.det(argmax),det(argmax)
```

and get

```
(1.5070856755023637e-12, -0.24884033203125, 165113593789.75116, 165113593790.0)
```

as the one with the highest relative error. My guess there is actually that your answer is better since the original matrix only contained integers so the determinant should be an integer.